# Select img tags which are having text logo any where in the html tag

Tags: html, regex, ruby, image

```
<img class="logo" src="/logo.png">
<img src="/product.png" id="logo">
<img 
   src="/product.png" 
   id="logo"
/>


<img class="with-text" src="            /portal-resource/portal-theme-images/regence/identity/regence-sun-cs.svg
    " alt="Regence-cs">


<img class="with-text" src="            /portal-resource/portal-theme-images/regence/identity/regence-sun-cs.svg
    " alt="Regence-cs logo">
```

My trial available at [A rubular trial](https://rubular.com/r/X16b9YZiHzG1bS)

Please guide me about selecting image tags which are having **logo** text anywhere in the entire tag

Answer (score 1):

I've checked this and works correct:

`<img\s+.*?src=['"]([^"']+).*? alt=\"(.*)logo(.*)\">`

Try once with this pattern, maybe it's suitable for your use case ...

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `<img(?=[^>]*logo)[^>]*\/?>`

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/3OBZsfNeVqVEbA)